# Convert Weiestrass Form to Legendre Form

Tags: elliptic-curves

If an Elliptic Curve is of the form E:y^2=x^3+ax+b then how do we convert this Legendre Form y^2=x(x-1)(x-L)?

Comment: Factor $x^3 + ax + b = (x-x_1) (x-x_2) (x-x_3)$.  Translate $x$ by $x_1$
to make the first factor $x$.  Then multiply $x$ by $x_2-x_1$ and
$y$ by $(x_2-x_1)^{3/2}$ and divide by $(x_2-x_1)^3$ to get
$y^2 = x (x-1) (x-L)$ with $L = (x_3-x_1)/(x_2-x_1)$.  If $x^3+ax+b$
does not factor completely then $L$ must be in a field larger than
the one used to define the curve.


Comment: @Noam: This is an answer, not a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://qchu.wordpress.com/2010/03/12/fractional-linear-transformations-and-elliptic-curves/